# Java BufferedImage getRGB method and Color class

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

What do the x and y parameters in the getRGB(x, y) method represent? What does the numerical return value represent?

How do I identify the color of specific pixels within a BufferedImage that is displayed on a DrawingPanel? Ideally I'd like to 'find' a word within an image, and underline or outline this word to create a relevant hyperlink. How can I translate these numerical values into human understandable colors like 'red' 'green' or 'blue'?

Yes, I understand that in the Color class an alpha value of 0-255 represents transparent to opaque. But what does this imply for the actual color? I'm happy to clarify if this doesn't make sense. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The x and y coordinates represent the **pixel location**, x going from left to right and y going from top to bottom (both starting at 0). So (0, 0) is the upper left pixel, and (width-1, height-1) is the bottom right pixel.

The integer value returned has the R, G, B and (potentially) Alpha values packed into a single int. Remember that an int contains 32 bits, so 8 of those bits are allocated to each of the values.

But, if you're not to good with shifting bits around inside an integer, the easiest thing to do is **pass the integer value to the constructor of Color**:

```
int rgba = image.getRGB(coordinates);
Color col = new Color(rgba, true);
int r = col.getRed();
int g = col.getGreen();
...
```

Obviously, recognising where a word is from raw pixel values is a whole nother, quite complex, problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A few follow up questions if you don't mind: I've implemented something similar, but am getting a "Coordinate out of bounds" error when I specify x and y to be anything above 84 each. But my DrawingPanel was established with the parameters 500, 500, so shouldn't they be within those bounds? Also, in the 32 bit representation, can you give me an idea of what each 8 bit value translates into? I.e., if I have the value 0000001, how much red is that? Does it just increase as the value increases? Thanks again.

Comment: Whaddya know, found out how to translate the numbers into colors too. If you still have insight that'd be great, but I've made some progress on my own.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to extract the colour components "manually", you would basically shift right by multiples of 8 and then AND with 255 (0xff). So (rgba & 0xff), (rgba >>> 8) & 0xff, (rgba >>> 16) & 0xff, (rgba >>> 24) & 0xff will give you the individual components. But if you're not too au fait with this, as I say, you may as well go via a Color wrapper.

Comment: hi @NeilCoffey  is there any way to get average rgb values of a specified area.. like getting average rgb values length wise for a bitmap .. i wanted to divide an image lengthwise to some 100 pieces vertically and get average rgb of each slice.... please help  . (i have upvoted ur answer :) )

Comment: @aav For many applications, I think you can really just calculate it as you'd expect: sum the relevant R, G and B values into 3 variables then divided each by the number of pixels sampled to get (R, G, B) for the average colour. If each 'band' involved a large number of pixels and speed was a concern, you could take the average of a random sample of, say, 100 pixels from the given band.