# What does this RGB value mean

Tags: java, image, rgb, pixel, bufferedimage

I am working with the method image.getRGB() and I am not sure what the int value i am getting means. It is returning a -1 and I'm not sure why. I just want to see whether a pixel is black or white.

Comment: Please post code; there's not enough information to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

a `-1` probably means 0xFFFFFF which is white?

Also see this question [Java BufferedImage getRGB method and Color class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517721/java-bufferedimage-getrgb-method-and-color-class) to convert an RBG int value into a `Color` instance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know that for java 4 bytes are needed to store int;

Secondly, the getRGB method returns alpha, red, green, and blue components of RGB, each occupies 1 bytes and one byte means 8 bits.

Thirdly, you might need to know alpha means the degree of opaque (means not transparent)

And, -1 in [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 (int 32 bits as mentioned above)

Finally  now you know that the alpha part is 255, so as red, green, blue. which mean, the color is not transparent and white.

Comment: does -16777216 mean that the pixel is black and not transparent?

Comment: -16777216 in 2's complement is 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000, so you're correct.